# test actionview got rake aborted. How to avoid the rake aborted?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake-test

I read [Contributing to Ruby on Rails — Ruby on Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/contributing_to_ruby_on_rails.html#running-tests)

about test for
[rails/rails at 4-2-stable: Ruby on Rails](https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/4-2-stable)

(commit number: e531c86e6bb0b623cd18c97a7a32ba981e8fb2ce)

In `rails/activerecord directory` on my Mac.

`% RUBYOPT=-W0 bundle exec rake test --trace`

I got `rake aborted!`

```
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [ruby -w -I"lib:test" -I"/Users/shingo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0" "/Users/shingo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/rake_test_loader.rb" "test/actionpack/abstract/abstract_controller_test.rb" "test/actionpack/abstract/helper_test.rb" "test/actionpack/abstract/layouts_test.rb" "test/actionpack/abstract/render_test.rb" "test/actionpack/controller/capture_test.rb" "test/actionpack/controller/layout_test.rb" "test/actionpack/controller/render_test.rb" "test/actionpack/controller/view_paths_test.rb" ]
```

How to avoid the rake aborted?

> ** Invoke test (first_time)
>   ** Invoke test:template (first_time)
>   ** Execute test:template /Users/shingo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/bin/ruby -w -I"lib:test" -I"/Users/shingo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0" "/Users/shingo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/rake_test_loader.rb"
>   "test/template/active_model_helper_test.rb"
>   "test/template/asset_tag_helper_test.rb"
>   "test/template/atom_feed_helper_test.rb"
>   "test/template/capture_helper_test.rb"
>   "test/template/compiled_templates_test.rb"
>   "test/template/date_helper_i18n_test.rb"
>   "test/template/date_helper_test.rb"
>   "test/template/dependency_tracker_test.rb"
>   "test/template/digestor_test.rb" "test/template/erb/form_for_test.rb"
>   "test/template/erb/tag_helper_test.rb"
>   "test/template/erb_util_test.rb"
>   "test/template/form_collections_helper_test.rb"
>   "test/template/form_helper_test.rb"
>   "test/template/form_options_helper_i18n_test.rb"
>   "test/template/form_options_helper_test.rb"
>   "test/template/form_tag_helper_test.rb" "test/template/html_test.rb"
>   "test/template/javascript_helper_test.rb"
>   "test/template/log_subscriber_test.rb"
>   "test/template/lookup_context_test.rb"
>   "test/template/number_helper_test.rb"
>   "test/template/output_safety_helper_test.rb"
>   "test/template/partial_iteration_test.rb"
>   "test/template/record_identifier_test.rb"
>   "test/template/record_tag_helper_test.rb"
>   "test/template/render_test.rb"
>   "test/template/resolver_patterns_test.rb"
>   "test/template/sanitize_helper_test.rb"
>   "test/template/streaming_render_test.rb"
>   "test/template/tag_helper_test.rb"
>   "test/template/template_error_test.rb"
>   "test/template/template_test.rb" "test/template/test_case_test.rb"
>   "test/template/test_test.rb"
>   "test/template/testing/fixture_resolver_test.rb"
>   "test/template/testing/null_resolver_test.rb"
>   "test/template/text_helper_test.rb" "test/template/text_test.rb"
>   "test/template/translation_helper_test.rb"
>   "test/template/url_helper_test.rb"  Run options: --seed 32409
>
> ## Running:
>
> ..................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................S...........................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................
>
> Finished in 11.824681s, 132.4349 runs/s, 301.3189 assertions/s.
>
> 1566 runs, 3563 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 1 skips
>
> You have skipped tests. Run with --verbose for details.
>   ** Invoke test:integration:action_pack (first_time)
>   ** Execute test:integration:action_pack /Users/shingo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/bin/ruby -w -I"lib:test"
>   -I"/Users/shingo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0" "/Users/shingo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/rake_test_loader.rb"
>   "test/actionpack/abstract/abstract_controller_test.rb"
>   "test/actionpack/abstract/helper_test.rb"
>   "test/actionpack/abstract/layouts_test.rb"
>   "test/actionpack/abstract/render_test.rb"
>   "test/actionpack/controller/capture_test.rb"
>   "test/actionpack/controller/layout_test.rb"
>   "test/actionpack/controller/render_test.rb"
>   "test/actionpack/controller/view_paths_test.rb"  Run options: --seed
>   62868
>
> ## Running:
>
> ...................................................................................................................F........................................................................................................
>
> Finished in 0.799071s, 275.3197 runs/s, 384.1961 assertions/s.
>
> 1) Failure:
>   RenderTest#test_locals_option_to_assert_template_is_not_supported
>   [/Users/shingo/Documents/workout/rails/actionview/test/actionpack/controller/render_test.rb:1267]:
>   --- expected
>   +++ actual @@ -1,2 +1 @@
>   -"the :locals option to #assert_template is only supported in a ActionView::TestCase
>   -"
>   +""
>
> 220 runs, 307 assertions, 1 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips rake aborted!
>   Command failed with status (1): [ruby -w -I"lib:test"
>   -I"/Users/shingo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0" "/Users/shingo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/rake_test_loader.rb"
>   "test/actionpack/abstract/abstract_controller_test.rb"
>   "test/actionpack/abstract/helper_test.rb"
>   "test/actionpack/abstract/layouts_test.rb"
>   "test/actionpack/abstract/render_test.rb"
>   "test/actionpack/controller/capture_test.rb"
>   "test/actionpack/controller/layout_test.rb"
>   "test/actionpack/controller/render_test.rb"
>   "test/actionpack/controller/view_paths_test.rb" ]
>   /Users/shingo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/testtask.rb:108:in
>   `block (3 levels) in define'
>   /Users/shingo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/file_utils.rb:57:in`
>   call'
>   /Users/shingo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/file_utils.rb:57:in
>   `sh'
>   /Users/shingo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/file_utils_ext.rb:37:in`
>   sh'
>   /Users/shingo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/file_utils.rb:96:in
>   `ruby'
>   /Users/shingo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/file_utils_ext.rb:37:in`
>   ruby'
>   /Users/shingo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/testtask.rb:104:in
>   `block (2 levels) in define'
>   /Users/shingo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/file_utils_ext.rb:58:in`
>   verbose'
>   /Users/shingo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/testtask.rb:100:in
>   `block in define'
>   /Users/shingo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:240:in`
>   call'
>   /Users/shingo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:240:in
>   `block in execute'
>   /Users/shingo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:235:in`
>   each'
>   /Users/shingo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:235:in
>   `execute'
>   /Users/shingo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:179:in`
>   block in invoke_with_call_chain'
>   /Users/shingo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/monitor.rb:211:in
>   `mon_synchronize'
>   /Users/shingo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:172:in`
>   invoke_with_call_chain'
>   /Users/shingo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:201:in
>   `block in invoke_prerequisites'
>   /Users/shingo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:199:in`
>   each'
>   /Users/shingo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:199:in
>   `invoke_prerequisites'
>   /Users/shingo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:178:in`
>   block in invoke_with_call_chain'
>   /Users/shingo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/monitor.rb:211:in
>   `mon_synchronize'
>   /Users/shingo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:172:in`
>   invoke_with_call_chain'
>   /Users/shingo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:165:in
>   `invoke'
>   /Users/shingo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:150:in`
>   invoke_task'
>   /Users/shingo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:106:in
>   `block (2 levels) in top_level'
>   /Users/shingo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:106:in`
>   each'
>   /Users/shingo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:106:in
>   `block in top_level'
>   /Users/shingo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:115:in`
>   run_with_threads'
>   /Users/shingo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:100:in
>   `top_level'
>   /Users/shingo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:78:in`
>   block in run'
>   /Users/shingo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:176:in
>   `standard_exception_handling'
>   /Users/shingo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:75:in`
>   run'
>   /Users/shingo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/bin/rake:33:in
>   `<top (required)>' /Users/shingo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin/rake:23:in`
>   load' /Users/shingo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
>   /Users/shingo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in`
>   eval'
>   /Users/shingo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in
>   `' Tasks: TOP => test => test:integration:action_pack

Comment: I don't see anything out of the ordinary here.

Comment: @sevenseacat why? Happened  `rake aborted! Command failed with status (1)`